# Is it okay to have more than one itemprop 'description' for one 'Product' in page?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to format a visual interface for specifications in my product aggregator website. Can I use more than one `itemprop="description"` for one `Product`?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div class="big1"> // align left width 50%
<img itemprop="image" src="phone_1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="big2"> // float left width 50% 
<div class="format1"> // align left
<span id="1" itemprop="name">phone 1 name</span> //50% align left
<span id="2" itemprop="description">phone 1 storage</span> //30% float left
<span id="3" itemprop="description">phone 1 RAM</span> //20% float left
</div>
<div class="format2"> // float left
<span id="4" itemprop="description">phone 1 screen type</span> //40% align left
<span id="5" itemprop="description">phone 1 resolution</span> //40% float left
<span id="3" itemprop="description">phone 1 camera</span> //20% float left
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider the following: How does Google determine a relevant description? Note that the Product type has many other properties besides the description. IMHO, many descriptions do not make sense.

Comment: This can cannibalize the contents of the properties description.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223906/can-you-have-multiple-itemprop-description-on-a-page), having multiple descriptions is acceptable in the Microdata standard.

Multiple descriptions pass the [Yandex Microdata validation tool](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/). I had to add some missing elements relating to '[offer](https://schema.org/Offer)' for your code to work.